# How do I set up Google Compute Engine as a HTTPS server?

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, routes, google-compute-engine

I'm running an app on a VM instance (instance-1) and would like myproject.appspot.com requests to be served by instance-1.

I read https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/routing but it wasn't clear.  Is there a way to say "send all traffic to my one instance"?

If I go to my (ephemeral) external IP address for that instance, I can see the server.  But, that won't work for an oAuth2 domain (no IP addresses allowed), so I need it to go through the named domain.

I'd be ok if I could use something constant like instance-1-dot-myproject.appspot.com but would prefer the base myproject.appspot.com to say "any instances?  great!  use that."

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use [Managed VMs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/). They give you the flexibility of Google Compute Engine but work more like the PaaS that is Google App Engine.

You don't create the Google Compute Engine VM instances yourself, however, Managed VMs will spin them up on demand, using the Docker image you provide as the container of the code, data, etc.

Note that as of 29 Sep 2015, per [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/):

> **Beta**
>
> This is a Beta release of Managed VMs. This feature is not covered by any SLA or deprecation policy and may be subject to backward-incompatible changes.